# Kivy error: raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)

Tags: python, kivy

I have searched and searched, and i just don´t get it. From what i understand from posted answers, the problem is the class is not defined or spelled badly, but i have gone back and forth through my code and i can´t see the problem. Right now i´m just trying to get the layout there is no funcionality. I have two files, the .py and the .kv file, the main .py is:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Noughtsandcrosses(Widget):
    pass


class nandxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Noughtsandcrosses()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nandxApp().run()
```

and the .kv file is:

```
#:kivy 1.0

<Noughtsandcrosses>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: self.size

    Threebythreeone:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            Image:
                source: "blank.png"
                size: 100, 100
```

running the .py file this is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "nandx.py", line 24, in <module>
     nandxApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "nandx.py", line 21, in build
     return Noughtsandcrosses()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 345, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self, ignored_consts=self._kwargs_applied_init)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 451, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 526, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Threebythreeone>
```

i´m trying hard to learn kivy but it´s so frustrating getting a random error like this, can anyone point out what i´ve done wrong please.

Comment: I have no experience of using kivy, I just read some docs of the .kv language. Where is the definition of your `Threebythreeone` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered the error, kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Threebythreeone> because you have a child widget ***Threebythreeone*** in the ***<Noughtsandcrosses>*** widget rule, nandx.kv

I recommend that you check out [Programming Guide » Kivy Basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html) and the example below.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Threebythreeone(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Noughtsandcrosses(BoxLayout):
    pass


class nandxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Noughtsandcrosses()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nandxApp().run()
```

### nandx.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Threebythreeone>:
    # orientation: 'horizontal'   # Commented off because this is the default

    Button:
        Image:
            source: "blank.png"
            size: 100, 100

<Noughtsandcrosses>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: self.size

    Threebythreeone:
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this totally fixed the error. I´m such a massive n00b, the dual file thing in kivy does my head in, just need to learn more about it :)

Comment: Believe me: your answer is a much better guide than the official one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you haven't declared the `Threebythreeone` before using it. You can declare it in python like you have with `Noughtsandcrosses` or declare it in your `kv` file as in my example below.

See [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) for more info about `kv` language.

Also, `Noughtsandcrosses` doesn't have a property `orientation`as far as I know. You should probably use `BoxLayout`.

And, I don't think how you built your button is going to work as you expect.
 See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392202/passing-image-object-as-a-button-background-in-kivy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489143/kivy-image-as-button) for some information.

Below will work:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
# This is all that is necessary to declare a class based on BoxLayout.
<Threebythreeone@BoxLayout>:

<Noughtsandcrosses>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: self.size

    Threebythreeone:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            Image:
                source: "blank.png"
                size: 100, 100
""")


class Noughtsandcrosses(BoxLayout):
    pass


class nandxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Noughtsandcrosses()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nandxApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the
orientation: 'horizontal'