# How to achieve a tabbed panel to be under the header (KivyMD/Python)?

Tags: tabs, kivy, kivymd

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcEJv.png)

I get this error:
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class

Maybe my tabs.kv is a bit wrong but I dunno in my case where or how to put TabbedPanel class.

My header.kv

```
<Header>
    name: 'header'
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Demo"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
            elevation: 4  # shadow
            font_size: 14
            md_bg_color: 0.21, 0.34, 0.43, 1     # 0,0 100/255, 1

        Widget:

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        BoxLayout:  # for the navigation drawer content
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: '8dp'
            padding: '8dp'

            Image:
                source: 'byard.png'
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Alejandro'
                font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            MDLabel:
                text: 'test'
                font_style: 'Caption'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Profile'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'account'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Email'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'email'
```

And my tabs.kv

```
<Tabs>
    name: 'tabs'
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Tabbedpanel
        do_default: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Start here"
        Label:
            text: "Hello"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Benefits"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Mental"
            Button:
                text: "Physical"
            Button:
                text: "Emotional"
            Button:
                text: "Spiritual"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Quotes"
        Image:
            source: "byard.png"
```

Lastly my main.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    Header:
    Tabs:
```

My main.py file

```py
from kivy.core.window import Window  # keeps it mobile size when testing
Window.size = (360,600)  # remove this when the app is done
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRect


class Header(Screen):
    pass

class Tabs(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Header(name='header'))
sm.add_widget(Tabs(name='tabs'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        sm = Builder.load_file("Main.kv")

        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

What I am trying to do is like the photo shows, to have my TabbedPanel and its tabs under the header (MDTopAppBar). I have separate kv files and its all interconnected but I'm missing something with TabbedPanel as that is causing error. Partially it could be bad syntax or indentation i guess but i think i dont know where to assign Tabbed panel or how

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125196/kivy-error-raise-factoryexceptionunknown-class-s-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much code and it is unreadable, but I made an application template for you, as in the picture, using the [MDTabs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/tabs/) of the [KivyMD](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. What you want to do should be implemented this way.

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """
<Tab>
    MDLabel:
        text: root.title
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: 'H2'


MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    
    MDTopAppBar:
        id: top_bar
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        title: 'Page title'
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: print(x)]]
        right_action_items: [['magnify', lambda x: print(x)], ['dots-vertical', lambda x: print(x)]]
        
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        tab_hint_x: True
        
"""


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    """
    Class implementing content for a tab
    """


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f'Item: {i + 1}'))

    def on_tab_switch(
            self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        """
        Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        """

        print(f"Welcome to {instance_tab.title}' tab'")


TestApp().run()
```